# Get the total cookie size of a website given its header

Tags: java, http, header, session-cookies

My problem is simple, I have to get the total cookie size (by bytes). I used the Http Header and called the set-cookie element:

```
public static String getCookiesField(URLConnection connection){
    return connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"); // it can return null
}
```

I get the result of the field as:

> dwsid=H-GOhXnQOVZU1SKVvlnOMJOYZq5CNAs9AUYMWArBVV00TnFO3a8VgoaUtl6wpJqgKWkidqt-y1ihDRm9yo3a7g==; path=/; HttpOnly

I don't know what it mean but I need to get the size of the cookie by bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getBytes()` on the string of the cookie.

If you're unsure *what* the cookie is, [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) can help you; the syntax can be lots of different things, like

```
Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; HttpOnly; Path=<path-value>
// or 
Set-Cookie: sessionid=38afes7a8; httponly; Path=/
```

The [getHeaderField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField(java.lang.String)) method returns a `String` of the cookie (the **value for the field Set-Cookie** in the Header).

---

The size of the `byte`s are calculated by `myBytes.length` (no `()`).

So you can get the size of the cookie like this:

```
String setCookieField = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
// check that cookie is not null
String[] cookieFields = cookie.split(";");
// the cookie name/value pair is typically first
String[] cookieNameValue = cookieFields[0].split("=");
String cookie = cookieNameValue[1];
int size = cookie.getBytes("UTF-8").length;
```

Comment: Great! :) and if it worked please mark the answer as accepted so that others can find it later

Comment: Done ! Thnk you brother

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution:

```
String cookie = "dwsid=H-GOhXnQOVZU1SKVvlnOMJOYZq5CNAs9AUYMWArBVV00TnFO3a8VgoaUtl6wpJqgKWkidqt-y1ihDRm9yo3a7g==; path=/; HttpOnly".split(";");
bytes b[] = cookie[0].getBytes();
return b.length;
```