# Cookies is get evicted on new key insert

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

There are some cookie like language, market etc.. which are essential for some functionality in website.

Recently I have observed that while navigating, all the cookies are getting cleared, causing application break.

In application we are using some analytics lib which are creating lot of cookies in same domain of our application. and I can see that as soon as cookie count reaches near 40, all the old cookies gets evicted (there is a limit on cookie size and count on browser).

Is there any way to tell the browser not to clear those essential cookies?

UPDATE:
Found the root cause of it, It was analytics libs (GTM), where developers were creating some cookies for tracking purpose. Have asked them to move to session storage, Now It works fine.

Comment: I strongly doubt whether the right, or only way to provision the required functionality is by dropping more than 40 cookies on the browser - this looks like an application design issue.

Comment: Browser does the clearing not the the application, I think you didnt read it properly/

Comment: No, I don't think you understand the problem: your application creates the cookies.

Comment: I do  understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately behavior across browsers is unpredictable.

One solution you can try is checking if the current cookie size limit is exceeded before adding / editing cookies. Info on getting cookie sizes: [Get the total cookie size of a website given its header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939368/get-the-total-cookie-size-of-a-website-given-its-header)

Most browsers set a limit of about 4096 bytes (or 4kB) of cookies per domain - or 50ish cookies max depending on the size of each of your cookies.

Comment: Thanks, But as I mentioned in I am aware of that limitation.